# PDO Delete Statement Issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having trouble with a delete statement. Some of my code is borrowed and its probably a simple mistake but i cannot figure it out. Im still learning so its probably not too efficient but i want to try and get it working to have a base to work from before i start refining my code more.

```
public function delete_data($id,$table){

    $sql = 'DELETE FROM `'.$table.'` WHERE `my_id` = :id';
    $this->prepare_qry($sql);
    $this->bind(':id',$id);
    $this->execute;

    $statement = print_r($this->stmt,true);
    echo "statement:" . $statement;
}
```

When i echo out this i get:

```
DELETE FROM `my_table` WHERE `my_id` = :id
```

So that looks fine. Here are some of the relevant functions also

```
// Create a new PDO instanace
try{
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    } catch(PDOException $e){ // Catch any errors
    $this->error = $e->getMessage();
}

// prepare the query
public function prepare_qry($query){
$this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

// add the type for the binding
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
if (is_null($type)) {
switch (true) {
        case is_int($value):
    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
    break;

        case is_bool($value):
    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
    break;

        case is_null($value):
    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
    break;

        default:
    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
}
}
// run the binding process
$this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

// execute query
public function execute(){
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}
```

When run the code i get the following error. Any ideas what the problem is:

```
Undefined property: Database::$execute
```

Comment: No, the `print_r` is not fine. It should print out an object, not a string. Then again, it doesn't relate to your problem. Do as the other people said (regarding `execute` vs `execute()`) and it should be fine.

Comment: Seems like this is the mistake `$this->execute;` add this `$this->execute();`

Comment: Thanks for the helpful replies, i read some articles which gave examples, i used these examples to build a mini project and i was having difficulty after switching to learning PDO. 

I like to learn by picking a project i find interesting then trying to make it work, i then learn as i go along, its not perfect and i should probably read more so i understand the code better but this works for me, thankfully there is genuine people here that are willing to help me along the way and this site has been a massive help along the way, im sorry if my question caused you offense Jake.

Comment: Christian, can you expand on print_r. Since i moved to learning PDO ive struggled to find an easy way to troubleshoot errors with MYSQL statements and i have found this method works, if there is another method that is better if you can share that i would be very appreciative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written `->execute`, not `->execute()`.

`->execute` is trying to access a property. `->execute()` is calling the function.